# Laptop switches off during Windows 10 installation

Tags: laptop, installation, windows-10

I'm trying to install Windows 10 on a brandnew laptop, an HP Pavilion Notebook (15-1b052ng) with an AMD Quad-Core A10-8700P. I tried several times but the computer turns off during the installation process every time. More precisely, it turns off after almost exactly 4 minutes regardless of the installation progress. Even if I don't install Windows but stay at the dialog where I have to enter my key, it turns off after 4 minutes and boots again.

I already returned the laptop and got a new one of the same kind. Same problem. I downloaded a Windows 10 ISO image and created a bootable USB-Stick (instead of the DVD I bought) but it doesn't help. Exactly the same behaviour.

However, I can start Linux Mint from a USB Stick and it works. At least the machine doesnt switch off after a certain time.

Any ideas are highly appreciated!

Comment: Try unplugging the battery before booting or installation. Run only on the AC adapter and report back if anything changes.

Comment: Are you sure your source of Windows 10 aren't corrupted ?
You try to install x64 or x86 '? Check drivers : http://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC-series/5355006/model/5393349 (it seems ok) Your pc overheating ? hears you scratch your hard disk ?

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help. Same behaviour.

Comment: I tried installing from a DVD I bought at amazon. Then I downloaded an ISO image to make a USB-Stick. Finally, I just tried the USB-Stick created with the tool provided by Microsoft. The PC is certainly not overheating. I'm also not hearing strange sounds. It just turns off after about 4min 30s, even when I dont' do anything but just wait at the dialog that lets me pick language and timezone.

Comment: How could I install different drivers?

Comment: I'm trying to install the x64 version. It's a 64bit processor with 8GB RAM.